# store data in one large table or create new table every month

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mariadb

I'm designing a table in mysql that storing thousand of devices and about hundred of records per device every 10 seconds. This table is aimed to log device data for analysis, some sort of historian or time series database but on transactional database.. It has 6 columns: ID (PK), Timestamp, TagID, DeviceID, Decimal Value, MessageID. I'm indexing Timestamp, TagID, DeviceID, Decimal Value. 
Do we have any potential problem when this table grow significantly large in term of dba, select query? Are we better off to create new table every month to keep the table size small? I'm not a database expert so I don't know which way are better. Would anyone please advice. Many thanks.

Comment: From what you say, you need to learn about partitions.

Comment: The size of the table does not matter most of the time if you have good indexes.  Sometimes it gets to the point where partitioning is useful.  It is rare that making a new table is a good idea

Comment: Thanks, I read somewhere about partitioning by hash...is this the way to go?

Comment: @PhuongLe everything works with hashes -- but that is internal.  You can partition by the field that has the date and pick month as the partition size -- for example.  It is sort of like archiving every month but better.  In any case you need to read some full articles on it or hire a DBA to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What will the `SELECTs` look like?  If you always want all the data for a given device&time, then pack them into a single column.  I suggest `JSON`-encoding.  Otherwise, you are asking for `INSERTing` 10,000 rows per second?

If you do need to keep the data items in separate rows, the be sure to use some form of batching -- multi-row `INSERT` (100 rows at a time), or LOAD DATA from a file.

When the table gets to be huge, there are many possible problems.  (Again, I need to see the `SELECTs` to go into more detail.)

`PARTITIONIng`?  Not likely to help.  Especially not `BY HASH`.  Multiple tables are not likely to help.  (Again, I need to see the `SELECTs` to go into more detail.)

"I'm indexing Timestamp, TagID, DeviceID, Decimal Value" -- Do you mean one-column indexes?  Likely to be very much a waste.  (Again, I need to see the `SELECTs` to go into more detail.)

If you need to do large `SELECTs` to summarize the data; then let's talk about Summary tables.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  You need to shrink the datatypes to save space.